# How to remove celery beat task in django

Tags: django, celery

I followed the doc (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) and write a Periodic Task , add CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE in django settings.py, and run it in supervisor:
celery -A proj worker -B

But now I do not want the Periodic Task anymore. I delete the schedule in settings.py, and change command in superviosor to:
celery -A proj worker
without celery beat, and reload it.

but once I run celery, there are still Periodic Tasks running.

I event delete all data in djcelery and celery beat pid file. But it does not help.

How can I remove the  Periodic Task ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

you can see SCHEDULED task by

celery beat --loginfo=DEBUG

After doing this, I found my task has been deleted.

But task queue has a lot of existing tasks. Just do:
celery -A proj purge